# Understanding sliding window technique via real example

Tags: cisco, tcp, bandwidth, transport-protocol

I have two questions:

1. Can someone simplify the knowledge of **windowing** that is commonly
   used by connection-oriented protocols like TCP? I generally
   understand it is a technique for flow control but I still don't see
   how it is implemented in a real example.
2. If I want to know the number of packets that can be received by a
   receiver in each second, is it reasonable to calculate it by
   `Bandwidth * Distance`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm not sure what you mean by a real example? If you want to see it
   in action, you can use something like Wireshark to capture a TCP
   conversation during a download. You could do a simple [Internet
   search](https://www.google.com/search?q=tcp%20windowing) to see a lot of contrived examples.
2. Your calculation is far short of what is needed to calculate TCP
   throughput. Also, you need to understand that dynamic factors like
   congestion will constantly change the throughput, with the windows
   growing and shrinking all the time to adapt to the changing network
   environment. Without a lot more information, it isn't possible to,
   "*know the number of packets that can be received by a receiver in
   each second*,"  and that number will change from second to second.